# iPhone: Deleted PNG File Keeps Loading into ImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have the following line of code which loads a png file into a `UIImageView`:

```
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
```

The problem is, I've long since deleted "Background.png" from the project and it's still being loaded! I've tried cleaning, building, deleting the app off the phone, restarting the phone, deleting the build folder in the project folder, deleting derived data, and it's still loading! Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried this answer?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570879/app-loads-a-deleted-picture

Comment: Since he says he tried 'deleting derived data' I'm afraid he already tried that without succes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was that the folder of an old target was still in my project folder (even after I deleted the target long ago). I deleted the folder, deleted the app off my phone, cleaned and rebuilt,  and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds terribly scruffy, but I've had similar problems before, and, personally, I'd just change the code to

```
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NewBackground.png"]];
```

and forget about it.

Comment: Does imageNamed not cache it? This might help me for when I'm testing so I don't have to keep cleaning this thing.

Comment: If the code calls for `NewBackground.png` and you actually get `Background.png` (a) I'd be surprised and (b) something would be very wrong indeed!